# How to resolve 409 page not found error on delete in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

[image]

```
    <form method="POST" action="/posts/{{$post->id}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
        <input type="submit" value="DELETE">
    </form>
```

I have this method which should invoke the 'destroy' method in 'PostsController'. But when I hit delete button I get "409 page expired" error.

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your form, add a `csrf` field. You can do it like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="/posts/{{$post->id}}">
        @csrf
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
        <input type="submit" value="DELETE">
    </form>
```

Read more about it here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf

Answer (score 1):

`csrf` missing.

You have to add `csrf` inside the form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```